# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException:

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to get elment by html selector
a lit of events from python.org

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_driver_path = "C:\development\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

driver.get("https://python.org")

event_time = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, ".event-widget time")

for time in event_time:
  print(time.text)
```

Comment: Can you tell us which element in the application you are trying to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locator type is wrong, it should be `CSS_SELECTOR` not `CLASS_NAME`, also you have to mention `find_elements` not `find_element`:

```
event_time = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".event-widget time")

for time in event_time:
  print(time.text)
```

Output:

```
2023-02-05
2023-02-16
2023-02-21
2023-02-25
2023-03-06
```

Answer (score 0):

About **Invalid Selector Exception**:

Selenium throws an InvalidSelectorException when an XPath or CSS selector does not conform to the XPath or CSS specification. In other words, an InvalidSelectorException occurs when you pass in a selector which can’t be parsed by Selenium WebDriver’s selector engine. This occurs when an element retrieval command is used with an unknown web element selector strategy

**Problem:**

In your case, I do not see any class attribute with the name ***.event-widget time*** in the entire HTML structure.

**Solution:**

Try using some other locators like ID, name or XPath. If you are specific about using ClassName, then make sure that web element's class attribute is accurately matching in your code.